# Calling on a Method to Display Output Names from Chat Log

Tags: java, regex, xml, methods

I'm having trouble with implementing a method into a bit of code for an output. Essentially, I created a method called `getName` which assigns a persons name to a unique number. Then, I get an input file containing chat logs. After I filter out the lines I need, I need it to be able to display the person's name instead of the number. Here is a snippet of my method:

```
public static String getName(int id) {
        // External identifiers specified
        switch (id) {
        case 5644:
            return "Steve Jobs";
        case 5640:
            return "John Smith";
        case 5663:
            return "Johnny Appleseed";
```

And here is the code that takes my input, and displays the output I need:

```
try
  {
  // assigns the input file to a filereader object
     BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log));

      sc = new Scanner(log);
            while(sc.hasNext())
              {
                 String line=sc.nextLine();
                   if(line.contains("LANTALK")){
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("
                    (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})\\s\\[D\\].+<MBXID>(\\d+)
                    <\\/MBXID><MBXTO>(\\d+)<\\/MBXTO>.+<MSGTEXT>(.+)
                    <\\/MSGTEXT>", Pattern.MULTILINE + Pattern.DOTALL); 
                    // Multiline is used to capture the LANMSG more than 
                    once, and Dotall is used to make the '.' term in regex 
                    also match the newline in the input
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                while (matcher.find())
                    {
                       String output = matcher.group(1) + " [" + 
                       matcher.group(2) + "] to [" + matcher.group(3) + "] " 
                       + matcher.group(4);
                       System.out.println(output);
                       System.out.println();
                    }

                   } // End of if

               } // End of while
```

Each line of output looks like this:

```
14:49:28.817 [1095] to [5607] I could poke around with it a bit and see what's available.
```

I just need the numbers `1095` and `5607` to display the person's name that I've specified in my method. So I'm asking how I implement that into my code? Is there a special way that I need to call upon the method in order for it to recognize the numbers? Do I use some sort of regular expression or XML? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**You should be using a Dictionary**

Benefits of using a dictionary:

- You would be able to access both the user's names and their ID numbers as key-value pairs.
- They are fast.
- You would eliminate the need for switch statements to keep track of user's IDs.

**Links:**

- [Associative Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (another name for dictionary)
- [Dictionaries, Hash-Tables and Sets](http://www.introprogramming.info/tag/dictionary-data-structure/)
- [Java Dictionary example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/data-types/java-dictionary-example/)